# getting Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN) when trying to display points from geojson

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet, gis, geojson

I tried to display the point from geojson but there is an error that I mentioned above. this is my source code

```
maps.setView(new L.LatLng(-8.203824, 113.175476), 12);

        L.geoJson(dataPelanggan, {
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                console.log(feature)
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    icon: L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'asset/img/marker.png',
                        iconSize: [38, 45]
                    })
                });
            },
            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popUp) {
                    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popUp);
                }
            }
        }).addTo(maps);
```

I'm using leaflet version 0.7.7 because there is some kind of source code algorithm that I use using that version, then I want to add this point to clarify the function of the feature that I created. can someone help me? sorry if my sentence is confusing.

**geojson got from api**

```
var dataPelanggan=[
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "jenis": "Pelanggan",
        "nosambungan": "519",
        "nama": "CHU",
        "alamat_pelanggan": "TEMPEH LOR",
        "Stan": "96",
        "popUp": "No. Sambungan : 519<br>Nama : CHU<br>Alamat : TEMPEH LOR<br>Stan : 96"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            "113.177157376778350",
            "-8.196966314315622"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "jenis": "Pelanggan",
        "nosambungan": "5110",
        "nama": "NUR",
        "alamat_pelanggan": "TEMPEH",
        "Stan": "125",
        "popUp": "No. Sambungan : 5110<br>Nama : NURY<br>Alamat : RAYA TEMPEH LOR<br>Stan : 125"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            "113.177076511097520",
            "-8.197180194910073"
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: What's the value of `dataPelanggan`?

Comment: some data such as name, address and coordinates @IvanSanchez